# LUIS Training failed: 404 Resource not found

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

After making changes in luis application like add or remove any utterances or entity in the luis portal we are facing an outage. If you are not doing any changes in the application then click on train button it will always display "train successful" message but after doing some changes then all luis app getting the 404 resource not found exception. We have mapped proper prediction resource with standard pricing tier.

There is no error logged in the azure portal and still luis application is up and running.

**Luis Information:**

1. Location -> West US
2. Luis Cog Pricing Tier -> Standard
3. Luis Authoring Service Pricing Tier -> FO

**Error Message :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The app is up and running now !

Thank you **LUIS Team** for fixing this internal outage.

[image]

Reference : [LUIS Team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/158913/unable-to-train-app-on-luis-portal-training-failed.html)